Can I use PowerBI with QuestDB?
I use PowerBI for exploratory data anaylsis and saw that QuestDB has Postgres connector support, but encountered some errors using it when I tried connecting the two.

Is PowerBI supported over Postgres wire or is there some other way I can use it with QuestDB?

QuestDB does support Postgres wire protocol, but some third party applications try to use Postgres-specific features that aren't supported.
As a workaround, you can use the Web connector against the /exp endpoint, which allows you to run queries and export a CSV. For example, with a url like:
http://localhost:9000/exp?query=tables()


QuestDB has a Grafana plugin, and users report that other tools such as Azure Data Studio and JetBrains IDEs work.
